# What would this code look like if instead of "async/await" use "then and catch"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is such a method in a React application:

```
fetchData = async () => {
   try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://........`);
    const data = (await response.json()).group;
    this.setState({
        data: data,
        car: Object.keys(data)[0] 
      },this.filter);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("404 Not Found");
    }
  };
```

How to write this part without async / await syntax, and using then and catch?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this!

```js
fetchData = () => {
    fetch("YOUR_URL")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => json.group)
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                data,
                car: Object.keys(data)[0] 
            },this.filter);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("404 Not Found");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply-

```
fetchData = () => {
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({data: data.group, car: Object.keys(data.group)[0]})
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If fetch returns a Promise you can:

```
fetchData = () => {
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => ... )
    .catch(err => ...)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetchData = () => {
    return fetch(`https://........`)
    .then(response => {
      const data = response.json().group;
      this.setState({
        data: data,
        car: Object.keys(data)[0] 
      },this.filter);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log("404 Not Found");
       });
   };
```

response.json() won't return a Promise so you don't need await